# How to configure PhpStorm to use symfony/phpunit-bridge

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, symfony3.x, symfony-3.4

I had problems with configuring PhpStorm IDE to use http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html while working with Symfony 3.3.

I decided to just download `phpunit.phar` to `bin` and use it instead.

Symfony 3.4 (and Symfony 4), does not even have `phpunit.xml.dist` out of the box, so there is a problem with using `phpunit.phar` easily.

I've installed PHPUnit using flex:

```
composer req phpunit
```

That created phpunit.xml.dist and I was able to run tests from command line by:

```
php bin/phpunit
```

But again I could not make PhpStorm use it.

So I downloaded `phpunit.phar` and it can work together with provided phpunit.xml.dist.

**Question 1:** Is there any way for PhpStorm IDE to use phpunit-bridge?

**Question 2:** What is the best practice for Symfony 4 (phpunit-bridge or vanilla phpunit.phar)?

Comment: But does it work in command line?

Comment: >php bin/phpunit  executes the tests

Comment: Also trying to launch via phpstorm, but the setup is quiet weird. What is the value of using phpstorm instead of a terminal console ? (which can be inside phpstorm itself)

Comment: You can run single tests from within the GUI. Just use shortcuts like CTRL-SHIFT-F10 to run specific test/class/directory, and SHIFT-F10 to execute last executed test. Also the output is parsed nicely, so you can actually jump to specific line in file just by clicking in output window.

Comment: DX in PHPStorm hurts too much. We don't use the Symfony bridge.

Comment: 1. require test-pack, 2. run php bin/phpunit on cli for download, 3. configure phpstorm: "path to phpunit.phar" > 'c:\project\path\bin\phpunit', "default configuration file" > 'c:\project\path\phpunit.xml.dist', 4. run tests - that's it

Answer (score 71, accepted):

What I usually do is point my phpunit testing framework on PHPStorm to the secret `.phpunit` directory which was created by the bridge, like:
[image]

The location of the "phar" file is:

```
bin/.phpunit/phpunit-(major).(minor)/phpunit
```

or in some cases:

```
vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-(major).(minor)/phpunit
```

---

After this, the specified `phpunit` executable will be called correctly when exeuting unit-tests, but with a `--no-configuration` option. This can cause autoloading problems (a lot of "class not found" errors), because the autoloader generated by Composer is not specified anywhere.

To fix this, you should have a `phpunit.xml` file in your project (this is common practice anyway), in which you specify Composer's autoloader, something like this:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
```

This `phpunit.xml` should then be specified in the "Default configuration file" option and you should be good to go.

---

Regarding phpstorm using phpunit-bridge:
It's possible as a custom script, but you won't have the nice interface and the possibility to run (and debug) specific tests via PHPStorm interface.

Comment: what should I do if I do not have this secret folder?

Comment: @syl.fabre then I'm not sure you're using phpunit-bridge

Comment: actually I've found out that this secret folder is created the first time you run `phpunit-bridge`. You should add this to your answer.

Comment: There's a button in the Phpstorm select file window (top right) so you can "see" the hidden files and directories.

Comment: To clarify it should be noted that the phpunit file in bin/.phpunit/phpunit-(major)-(minor)/ is a file generated by the phpunit-bridge so you are not using the vanilla phpunit

Comment: This is the right solution, using the bridge instead an only library is "as Symfony point of view" the best choice, this works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: in addition to @syl.fabre, you run phpunit-bridge from root doing this from the project root: ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit

Comment: Since the Symfony 5.1, you can also use the following stable path (not version dependent): `vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit/bin/simple-phpunit`

Answer (score 29):

I manage to run symfony/phpunit-bridge with success using this configuration:

- PhpStorm 2018.2.5
- Symfony 4.1.x
- PHP 7.1 running on docker
- "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0"

## Steps:

after `composer require --dev symfony/test-pack` i have in dir `/vendor/bin` file `simple-phpunit` which should run `symfony/phpunit-bridge` just fine.

Then in PhpStorm in `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Test Frameworks` set:

- radio select to `Path to phpunit.phar` option
- `Path to phpunit.phar` to absolute path of `simple-phpunit` file (e.g `/application/vendor/bin/simple-phpunit`)
- check `Default configuration file:` and set input value to absolute localization of your `phpunit.xml.dist` (in my case `/application/phpunit.xml.dist`)

[image: phpstorm phpunit settings]

note: `phpunit.xml.dist` file should be configured to use `symfony/phpunit-bridge` - check https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html

Click Appply/Ok and now you can run tests from PhpStorm interface

Comment: This also works when configuring WSL as the "PHPUnit by Remote Interpreter" type. Make sure to configure the whole absolute path to `simple-phpunit` and the Test Runner Default configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

Aside given answer, it's worth mentioning that the secret `.phpunit` directory won't appear out of thin air.

After `composer req phpunit`, one has to run the `phpunit` script first, eg.:

```
bin/phpunit
```

which will download a local copy of the PHPUnit and place it in the same folder, so the path to the phar executable will be:

```
// path may differ, at the time being is:
bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5-0/phpunit
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me using PHPStorm 2020.1 with Symfony 5.2

I found that it works if I apply a blank value for 'Path to phpunit.phar', despite the fact that the preferences dialog complains that '!Path to phpunit.phar is empty'.

So in Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Test Frameworks:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple and doesn't matter version of Symfony, because of the concept of testing still stable. At first, you need to configure test framework on the PHPstorm preferences ([screenshot](http://take.ms/Fw5pO)), in your case, you can to use Vendored PHPUnit or downloaded manually, you can join in the `PHPUnit library` section. Then you need to add [`Run/Debug` configuration](http://take.ms/y2bXy).
`"phpunit/phpunit"` and `"symfony/phpunit-bridge"` as I see was installed, this is all.

Comment: I know that i can use Vendored PHPUnit instead of phpunit.phar, but that is not an improvement. php bin/phpunit  (for Symfony4) will not even isntall phpunit in vendor, but in "bin" subdirectory. I was hoping for some clear advice how to configure PhpStorm to actually use symfony/phpunit-bridge not vanilla phppunt